# Solspace Freeform inline errors / Ajax validation and composer

Tags: solspace-freeform, error, validation

I'm using Solspace Freeform with a composer to built forms and found that I can use inline errors and Ajax validation with Freeform [here](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#examples), but documentation doesn't mention how to use it with a composer, only with form templates.

Any tips on that?

Thanks

Comment: In order to use AJAX with Freeform Pro you create the form in the composer and then embed that form into a hidden template. You then create an additional html form manually which will actually be used and filled in by users. When you submit this form, you use AJAX to post it to the hidden template you previously created where it gets submitted and processed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use AJAX with Freeform Pro you create the form in the composer and then embed that form into a hidden template. You then create an additional html form manually which will actually be used and filled in by users. When you submit this form, you use AJAX to post it to the hidden template you previously created where it gets submitted and processed.

Comment: OP is related to form validation using inline errors or AJAX validation, which based on current documentation I have no clue how to use with the composer. Also documentation is not talking about two same forms to get AJAX validation or inline errors to work.

Comment: This is the technique I have used for AJAX submission of Freeform pro forms. It's incredibly useful if you want a form with heavily customised elements that the composer won't let you create - such as styled radio buttons, select boxes etc.